# Easiest way to get hard disk sectors write statistics in Linux

Tags: linux, storage, usage-statistics, flash-memory

Im working on data logger software and hardware for Raspbery Pi. Raspberry Pi is using SD card for storage. I need to insert measurement results into database every second.

I want to do some investigation with few databases and get some statistical data how frequent sectors (memory cells on flash memory) to approximate how long my flash memory will work in my application.

Im worried about single cell program/erase cycles. For example - Round Robin Archives (used by RRDTool) have fixed size, pre-allocated storage and data like current record or last instert timestamp are always written at 1 address in that fixed file.

Is there any easy way to gather/log write commands with address in linux?

Comment: @Johnlcf thanks, I think this is what i need. Shall I delete this question or you can add answer with some details so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try blktrace(8), you can get more info by man page or:
http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~aaronc/iosched/doc/blktrace.html